# *Python* 406 not acceptable

Tags: python-3.x, http, flask

I am getting 406 not acceptable when i try to access http://localhost:5000/soap/someservice

> API Error: The resource identified by the request is only capable of generating response entities which have content characteristics not acceptable according to the accept headers sent in the request. Supported entities are text/html.

**Here is a snippet from the server side**

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_accept import accept
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/soap/someservice')
@accept('text/html')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'
```

**What i tried on the client side:**

```
from suds.client import Client
url = 'http://localhost:5000/soap/someservice?wsdl'
client = Client(url)

406 not acceptable

import requests
r=requests.get("http://localhost:5000/soap/someservice", headers={"content-type":"text"})
print(r)

406 not acceptable
```

All solutions give the same error any hints ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have specified

```
@accept('text/html')
```

In the Flask endpoint, but you have not provided an [Accept Header](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) specifying `text/html` in your request. Compare running your Flask app, but using:

```
In [3]: import requests
   ...: r=requests.get("http://localhost:5000/soap/someservice", 
                       headers={"Accept":"text/html"})
   ...: print(r)
   ...:
<Response [200]>
```